# How to avoid zigzag lines in matplotlib pyplot.plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression

```
X = (6 * np.random.rand(10, 1) - 3)
y_cap = (0.44530754 * X**2)+(1.01366334 * X)+0.13309963
plt.plot(X, y_cap, ls = '--')
```

I'm solving a polynomial regression problem (degree=2). I got the coefficients of X, X^2, and performed the polynominal regression. And now when I tried to plot using the above code I got these lines instead of a curve. How to solve this?
[image: Image: the plot]

Comment: has your issue been solved?

Comment: Thank you. It has been resolved. I sorted like this X=np.sort(X, axis = 0). But I have a small doubt: After performing sorting if I use a scatter plot (X,y) to see data points I saw they were more scattered. So I plotted the scatter plot and then I sorted X and plotted the curve, it's now correct. I don't know why sorted changed the data points on the scatter plot before. Can I know why?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your `X` values are not ordered. Just do this before calculating `y_cap`:

```
X = np.sort(X, 0)
```

Then it will work. Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = (6 * np.random.rand(10, 1) - 3)

X = np.sort(X, 0)

y_cap = (0.44530754 * X**2)+(1.01366334 * X)+0.13309963
plt.plot(X, y_cap, ls = '--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how did you create `X`?

Comment: it's impossible that it doesn't work in the X values are sorted

Comment: This is how is created it: X = 6 * np.random.rand(m, 1) - 3

Comment: ah that's because the shape is `(None, 1)`. I'll update my answer